Question of section 1.3 Intuition for Aborting in "Fiat-Shamir With Aborts: Applications to Lattice and Factoring-Based Signatures"
When I'm reading this paper "Fiat-Shamir With Aborts: Applications to Lattice and Factoring-Based Signatures" by Lyubashevsky. I have trouble understanding section 1.3 Intuition for Aborting.
"Then, with very high probability, the value of $sc+y$ will be in $[R,...,2^{64}R]$, in which case it will be impossible to determine anything about $sc $ if nothing is known about y."
And "Our solution is to instead pick $y$ from a much smaller set, something analogous to $[0,...,2R]$, but only reveal $ sc + y$ if it falls into the range $[R,...,2R]$. "
Do these sentences mean that $ sc+y $ is unsecure in $ [0,...,R]$, and why?
I would appreciate your response, thank you so much!

Yes, $sc+y$ is insecure in the full range. This is because inverting $AZ+TC$ to find a valid $Z$ is trivial using standard linear algerbra tools such as Gaussian elimination.
However, it's very difficult to find a valid $Z$ that have small norm. This is the Short Integer Solution the SIS problem.
